# FPS not spawn good in the scene (Multiplayer)

Tags: unity-game-engine

I make a 3d game with a fps controller.

I use 2 cameras

- one for the player
- and one for the scene.

I add an empty GanmeObject named `:NetworkManager` and add the `NetworkManager` script and `NetworkManagerHUD`.

My player has a lot of scripts that include a joystick and a button to shoot.

The camera of the player has a script too for rotation and the gun has a script too .

I saved the player as a prefab but all the joystick and button is in a canvas (so I made a prefab for the FixedJoystick and button , and gunshot point)

I add them in the prefab of the player and they don't appear in the Scene Prefab.

When I try to spawn the player in the game, the joystick and button shot and fps camera don't work and appear.

**What can I do when I start the game to start the fps mode?**

[image: scene prefab]

Comment: Did you only reference them so are those separate prefabs?  or are they placed in the same prefab? What is a `Scene Prefab`? Do you mean the instance of the Player prefab? Or are those references from the Scene -> spoiler: You can not store scene references in a prefab.

Comment: They are separate prefabs , I drag them in the project . How can I make the game to start from the player view camera with the joystick and button appear?

Comment: Is the joystick and button canvas part of the player prefab or do u add it in on the player prefab?

Comment: I add them to the prefab .. when I first made the player prefab they dissapear